# Robotframework - adb clearing user data is forbidden

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, appium, robotframework

I need to run mobile browser on android devices, however i am hitting this error

```
WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pm clear com.android.chrome' exited with code 255'; Stderr: 'Security exception: adb clearing user data is forbidden.

java.lang.SecurityException: adb clearing user data is forbidden.
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.clearApplicationUserData(ActivityManagerService.java:7612)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runClear(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1616)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:199)
        at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:103)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:24713)
        at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:634)
        at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:532)
        at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:3075)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:4713)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)'; Code: '255'
```

`androidUseRunningApp` or `noReset True` doesn't work for me

Does anyone now how to overcome this error?
This is what i am trying

```
AndroidConnection
    ${Options}    Create Dictionary    androidPackage    com.android.chrome
    ${caps}    Create Dictionary    chromeOptions    ${Options}
    Set to Dictionary    ${caps}    platformName    Android
    Set to Dictionary    ${caps}    platformVersion    9.0
    Set To Dictionary    ${caps}    deviceName    emulator-5554
    Set To Dictionary    ${caps}    browserName    Chrome
    Set To Dictionary    ${caps}    noReset    true
    Create Webdriver    Remote    command_executor=http://localhost:4723/wd/hub    desired_capabilities=${caps}
    go to    https://google.com
    Close Browser
```

```
AndroidConnection
    ${Options}    Create Dictionary    androidPackage    com.android.chrome
    ${caps}    Create Dictionary    chromeOptions    ${Options}
    Set to Dictionary    ${caps}    platformName    Android
    Set to Dictionary    ${caps}    platformVersion    9.0
    Set To Dictionary    ${caps}    deviceName    emulator-5554
    Set To Dictionary    ${caps}    browserName    Chrome
    Set To Dictionary    ${caps}    androidUseRunningApp    true
    Create Webdriver    Remote    command_executor=http://localhost:4723/wd/hub    desired_capabilities=${caps}
    go to    https://google.com
    Close Browser
```

Comment: are you using rooted device ?

Comment: No, I use non rooted device (Realme C2)

Answer (score 1):

1. Start the Android SDK's Android Debug Bridge (adb) server:

   ```
   adb start-server
   ```
2. If testing on Chrome app prior to version 33, ensure adb shell has read/write access to /data/local directory on the device:

   ```
   adb shell su -c chmod 777 /data/local
   ```

run this command , there will be a notifcation on your phone . clickk accept

else set chrome option ,

```
 detach:false
```

Comment: I am getting `/system/bin/sh: su: not found` error when execute `adb shell su -c chmod 777 /data/local` . I use chrome version 91 on mobile

Comment: make sure you start adb start-server, are you able to see the devices using adb devices ? have you enabled developer mode ? have you enabled usb debuuging ?

Comment: Yes i have start-server, can see devices with `adb devices` and can connect to devices when i run `adb shell` however I got an error when run `su` command on adb shell. An fow another option using `detach:false` how to add this option in robotframework?

`
AndroidConnection
    ${Options}    Create Dictionary    androidPackage    com.android.chrome
    ${caps}    Create Dictionary    chromeOptions    ${Options}
   Set To Dictionary    ${caps}    detach     false
`

still receive the same error adb clearing data is forbidden

Comment: Does anyone know how to overcome this issue?